# NDepend can't find attribute from mscorlib in rule

Tags: ndepend

I'm trying to exclude interop structs (structs having explicit struct layout) from getting "dead field" warnings from NDepend. My query with the added attribute filter looks like this:

```
warnif count > 0
from f in JustMyCode.Fields where
  f.NbMethodsUsingMe == 0 && 
  !f.IsPublic &&    
  !f.IsLiteral &&    
  !f.IsEnumValue &&  
  f.Name !=  "value__" &&       
  !f.ParentType.HasAttribute("System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute") &&  
  !f.IsGeneratedByCompiler
```

But NDepend will complain that StructLayoutAttribute is not a valid type name. mscorlib is listed under `<FrameworkAssemblies>` in the ndproj file.

I notice many rules in the default rule set have `AllowNoMatch()` when using system types from mscorlib. For example, the rules regarding DllImport use

```
 m.HasAttribute ("System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute".AllowNoMatch()) &&
```

What does that mean? Is that there to prevent the rule from choking when the user hasn't referenced mscorlib in the `<FrameworkAssemblies>` list? Or am I misunderstanding something about how NDepend actually resolves third party types?
I add `.AllowNoMatch()` there is no longer a syntax error, but of course the rule now reports my struct fields as unused.

Comment: the problem is that this attribute is special, it is used by the compiler to layout fields but it is not stored in the IL compiled code from which NDepend get this kind of data, so this is not feasible  https://www.ndepend.com/docs/ndepend-analysis-inputs-explanation

Comment: Thanks, you can turn that into an answer if you want. What would be a decent workaround (short of making a custom attribute on each struct to have Ndepend leave them alone)? I have all these in `NativeMethods` nested classes. Perhaps looking for ParentType.ParentType.SimpleName == "NativeMethods"?

Comment: Yes a custom attribute sounds good, but then you need to discipline yourself to not miss the pair of attributes which is an extra dev burden. I don't understand how NativeMethods are related to your question?

Comment: I have tons of these interop structs but they are always nested inside nested types called "nativemethods". So they are 2 levels nested.
SomeType.NativeMethods.SomeInteropStruct